# Confusion on the Origin of Summation Approximations in the Mean Field Ising Model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, ising-model, ferromagnetism

Much of the literature on the mean field approximation to the Hamiltonian of the Ising Model seems to take the the treatment of the summations in the model as a trivial step to the full mean field Hamiltonian; however, I cannot seem to wrap my head around these seemingly trivial approximations. First, just considering the Hamiltonian by itself:

$$H=-\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j-\mu B \sum_i \sigma_i$$

The typical first step in the approximation is to assume that the average spin is equal to some constant order parameter, m, i.e.

$$\langle \sigma_{i \text{ or } j}\rangle=m$$

Then by cutely adding zero to each of the sigmas, we can obtain:

$$H=m^2\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}-m\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}(\sigma_i+\sigma_j)-\mu B \sum_i \sigma_i$$

The next step is where I get fairly confused. Let us assume that each of the nearest atoms to site i are equidistant so that the wave functions of each atom overlap by an equal amount and hence J is constant for each lattice site (ridding the necessity for indices over J). Moreover, let us assume that there are N lattice sites with z nearest neighbors (which depends upon the number of dimensions, including time), then the nearest neighbor sums are treated, though very rarely explained, to become:

$$m^2\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}-m\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}(\sigma_i+\sigma_j) \implies \frac{1}{2}NzJm^2-mJz\sum_i \sigma_i$$

My confusion seems to stem from a lack of understanding of where the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ comes from as well as the treatment of the second sum:

$$-m\sum_{\langle ij \rangle}J_{ij}(\sigma_i+\sigma_j) \implies -mJz\sum_i \sigma_i$$

where it seems that the second sum rids the half (perhaps by assuming that $\sigma_i+\sigma_j=2\sigma_i$? This makes sense if we are talking in terms of assuming that the fluctuations are small, but does not seem to make sense in terms of how we carry out the sum over the nearest neighbors, as we are not summing these individually in the nearest neighbor summation).

Thank you ahead of time for your aid in clearing up potentially trivial confusion.

Comment: The factor $1/2$ comes from the fact that one sums over each pair $\langle ij\rangle$ only once, that is, one is getting $m^2 J$ for each edge of the lattice, of which there are $Nz/2$ (since each edge is shared by two vertices). For the second sum, notice that the term $\sigma_i$ appears exactly once for each edge of the lattice (since $\sigma_i+\sigma_j$ gives a contribution for each of the two endpoints of the edge $\langle ij\rangle$), therefore $\sum_{\langle ij\rangle} (\sigma_i+\sigma_j) = z\sum_i \sigma_i$, since there are $z$ edges having $i$ as an endpoint.